# select2, manually assing a value, but when try to get the value it returns null

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a weird situation
Accordigin to select 2 documentation
I can manually assing a value using

```
$("#e1").select2("data",{id:"4", text: "some value" });
```

but when try to get the value using
    $("#e1").val()
is returning null

Am I missing something?

Here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mspasiuk/j69821ce/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), calling the data function "Gets or sets the selection." It does not actually create any options.

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j69821ce/6/) which initializes the select in the HTML:

```
<select id="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option value="5">Other Value</option>
    <option value="4">some value</option>
</select>
```

You can see that when the select2 initializes and you call the data function, the 2nd option will be selected.

Comment: Cool, but how to add that option? I start with an empty select2. This is no about using the callback to set initial value, is about to properly set the option I was trying to add.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to bind it to `<input type="hidden" />` according to the documentation. A working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j69821ce/8/) which shows how a data array can be passed to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 problems, the first is that when you need to add data from js code and not explicit in HTML (using `<option>` tag), it's better to use an `input` instead of `select` and the second is you want to read selected data before selecting any data or event set an option as default.

So modify your HTML like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="e1" style="width:200px;"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="t1"></input>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

And JS like this:

```
$("#e1").select2({"data":[{id:"1", text: "some value 1" }, {id:"2", text: "some value 2" }]});

$("#Submit").click(function(){
    $("#t1").val("option 1: "+ $("#e1").val());
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j69821ce/9/)**